# Vic can beat Harold by $1/10$ of a mile in a $2$ mile race. Harold can beat Charlie by $1/5$ of a mile in a $2$ mile race. Very Confused.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, solution-verification, recreational-mathematics, word-problem

Vic can beat Harold by $1/10$ of a mile in a $2$ mile race. Harold can beat Charlie by $1/5$ of a mile in a $2$ mile race. If Vic races Charlie how far ahead will he finish?

Now I don't know the correct answer but I've done the problem in $2$ different ways and got $2$ different answers‍♂️

Let V be Vic, H be Harold and C be Charlie.
In V and H race V covers $2$ miles while H covers $2 - 1/10 = 1.9$ miles. In H and C race H covers $2$ miles while C covers $2 - 1/5 = 1.8$ miles

If H covers $1.9$ miles then C covers $(1.8)*(1.9)/2 = 1.71$ miles. Hence V is $2-1.71=0.29$ miles ahead.

Second method:

$V/H=2/1.9$

$H/C=2/1.8$

$V/C=200/171$

Since $V$ runs for 2 miles, $C$ runs $2(170)/200=1.7$ miles Hence V is ahead by $2-1.7=0.3$ miles.

Now there were four options after I've searched the problem online but in book there wasn't any options.
(A)
$0.15$ miles
(B)
$0.22$ miles
(C)
$0.25$ miles
(D)
$0.29$ miles
(E)
$0.33$ miles

But I don't understand If my second method is wrong or not since I've used it successfully to solve problems like this before.

Comment: It depends on how fast each runs on that final race: you cannot predict the outcome. Even if you make the assumption that each will run at the same speed that they ran in the previous race, it depends on how long the race is (something which you don't specify for the final race).

Comment: I think the easiest way to do this is to let $x=$ harolds speed.  Vics speed ie $\frac 2{1.9}x$ (he can run $2$ miles while harold run $1.9$) and Charles's speed is $\frac {1.8}2x$.  $\frac {\text{Charles' speed}}{\text{Vic's speed}}=\frac {\frac{1.8}2x}{\frac {2}{1.9}x} = \frac {1.8*1.9}{4}$.  Is if Vic runs $2$ miles then Charles will run $2*\frac {1.8*1.9}4 = \frac {3.42}2 = 1.71$ so Charles lost by $2-1.71=0.29$ miles. ... Hmm, not that i typed that out it doesn't seem as easy as i thought it'd be.  But it is a third method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your error was changing $171$ to $170$ when you inverted $V/C=200/171$ to obtain what should have been $2(171)/200=1.71$. The subtraction would have then given the correct answer, $2-1.71=0.29$, again.

Comment: Feeling very embarrassed right now, thanks for pointing it out :)

Comment: It's almost always easier to see someone else's errors.  Something about motes and beams, I think.

Answer (score 1):

Notice, the speeds of all three racers remain constant from one race to the other.

**Race-1** Let $t_1$ be the time taken to complete race-1. Then the speeds of Vic & Harold $V$ & $H$ respectively are given as
$$V=\frac{2}{t_1}, \ \  \ H=\frac{2-0.1}{t_1}=\frac{1.9}{t_1}$$

**Race-2** Let $t_2$ be the time taken to complete race-2. Then the speeds of Harold & Charlie $H$ & $C$ respectively are given as
$$H=\frac{2}{t_2}, \ \  \ C=\frac{2-0.2}{t_2}=\frac{1.8}{t_2}$$
Equating the speeds of Harold,
$$\frac{1.9}{t_1}=\frac{2}{t_2}\implies \frac{t_1}{t_2}=\frac{1.9}{2}$$

**Race-3** Vic will cover a distance of $2$ miles in time $t_1$ (which is also equal to the time taken in race-1) to finish race-3. Then the distance covered by Charlie in the same time $t_1$ of race-3 $$=\text{speed of Charlie}\times \text{time} t_1=\frac{1.8}{t_2}\times t_1$$
$$=1.8\left(\frac{t_1}{t_2}\right)=1.8\left(\frac{1.9}{2}\right)=1.71\ \text{miles}$$
Hence, in race-3, Vic beats Charlie by $2-1.71=\color{blue}{0.29\ \text{miles}}$

Answer (score 1):

If Vic beats Harold by 1/10 of a mile in a 2 mile race (i.e. he completes 2 miles when Harold is at 1.9 miles), his velocity $V$ is $20/19$ than that of Harold. Similarly, if Harold can beat Charlie by 1/5 of a mile in a 2 mile race (i.e. he completes 2 miles when Harold is at 1.8 miles), his velocity $H$ is $20/18=10/9$ than that of Charlie. If we call $C$ the velocity of Charlie, we have $$V=\frac{20}{19}\cdot H=\frac{20}{19} \cdot \frac{10}{9} \cdot C =\frac{200}{171} C$$

and then

$$C=\frac{171}{200} \,V$$

Therefore, in the same time in which Vic completes 2 miles,  Charlie completes $171/200$ of the course, that is to say $2\cdot 171/200=1.71$ miles. So, when Vic finishes, the difference with Charlie is

$$2 -1.71=0.29 \text{ miles} $$

Comment: Ok, I made the final part clearer.

Comment: Since the time for the race to end is the same for both Vic and Charles d/r = d/r 2/V = (2-x)/C, 2/V = (2-x)/171V/200, hence with simplification x = 0.29. Imo the last part should've clarified what process was going on instead  of taking the last leap without any variables but regardless I enjoyed this answer and learned alot thanks  .